# SendGrid -> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I'm fairly new to this, but I've basically copied the example straight from github and gotten the error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`. I believe I'm setting the environment variable correctly, just not really sure what I'm missing. Thanks for the help.

```
import sendgrid
import os

sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('Recip <redacted@gmail.com>')
message.set_subject('Example')
message.set_html('Body')
message.set_text('Body')
message.set_from('Sender <redacted@gmail.com>')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
print(status, msg)
```

Comment: Could you show full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the true issue was, but deleting the API key and generating a new one fixed it right away. Thanks, guys!